# Delete object (Table) in Maximo from database

Tags: database, maximo

What are all the tables do I need to take care of while deleting object (Table) from database Maximo.

Below are few tables i am aware of

SELECT * FROM ABCD;

SELECT * FROM MAXOBJECT WHERE OBJECTNAME='ABCD';
SELECT * FROM MAXOBJECTCFG WHERE OBJECTNAME='ABCD';

SELECT * FROM MAXATTRIBUTE WHERE OBJECTNAME='ABCD';
SELECT * FROM MAXATTRIBUTECFG WHERE OBJECTNAME='ABCD';

select * from maxtable where tablename = 'ABCD'; 
SELECT * FROM MAXSEQUENCE WHERE TBNAME='ABCD';

SELECT * FROM MAXSYSINDEXES WHERE TBNAME='ABCD';
SELECT * FROM MAXRELATIONSHIP WHERE PARENT='ABCD';

Suggest me the remaining tables to avoid creation of any orphan records.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the tables taken care of

SELECT * FROM MAXOBJECT WHERE OBJECTNAME='A_NEWOBJECT';
SELECT * FROM MAXOBJECTCFG WHERE OBJECTNAME='A_NEWOBJECT';

SELECT * FROM MAXATTRIBUTE WHERE OBJECTNAME='A_NEWOBJECT';
SELECT * FROM MAXATTRIBUTECFG WHERE OBJECTNAME='A_NEWOBJECT';

SELECT * FROM MAXTABLE WHERE TABLENAME='A_NEWOBJECT';
SELECT * FROM MAXTABLECFG WHERE TABLENAME='A_NEWOBJECT';

SELECT * FROM MAXSEQUENCE WHERE TBNAME='A_NEWOBJECT';
SELECT * FROM MAXSYSINDEXES WHERE TBNAME='A_NEWOBJECT';

SELECT * FROM A_NEWOBJECT;